# To which value does this infinite sum of power series coefficients converge?

Tags: nt.number-theory, limits-and-convergence, riemann-hypothesis

**Context:**

In [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1317045228) and [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1229696537) paper, J. Arias de Reyna shows that the RH follows when:

$$1.2663935... \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n^2 \le  1.2723669...$$

where $A_n$ is the coefficient in the following power series expansion:

$$\log\big((s-1)\,\zeta(s)\big)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n\left(1-\frac{1}{s}\right)^n $$

This fractional linear transformation maps the half plane $\Re(s) > \frac12$ onto the unit disc $|1-\frac{1}{s}| < 1$.

**Analogy:**

We know that the non-trivial zeros $\rho$ of $\zeta(s)$ drive the oscillating (error) term in the prime counting function(s). Analogously, the zeros $\mu = 0 \pm 2\pi n i$ induce the oscillating (sawtooth) behaviour in the [integer counting function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468334/an-integer-counting-function-nx). The entire function associated with the $\mu$s is $\xi_i=\frac{2}{s}\sinh\left(\frac{s}{2}\right)$.

Most of the well-known properties derived for the $\zeta$ or [Riemann $\xi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function)-functions, like the Hadamard product, Li's criterion, various power series expansions of log or log derivatives and their relations, etc., do exist in a very similar fashion for $\xi_i$. I believe the equivalent for $A_n$, let's name it $\hat{A}_n$, now maps $\Re(s)>0$ onto the unit disc $\big|\frac{s-1}{s+1}\big| < 1$, and has the power series expansion:

$$\log(\xi_i(s))=\log(\mathbb{e}-1) -1 +\frac{s}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \hat{A}_n\left(\frac{s-1}{s+1}\right)^n$$

where the coefficients have the following closed form:

$$\hat{A}_m =  \frac{(-1)^m-1}{m} - \sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^j\,{m-1 \choose j-1}\frac{2^j}{\Gamma(j+1)} \sum_{k=0}^{j-1}\frac{\Gamma(j-k)\,S(j, j-k)}{(\mathbb{e}-1)^{j-k}} \tag{1}$$

with $S(a,b)$ being the [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Since all $\mu$s reside on the line $\Re(s) = 0$, I think it should follow that:
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \hat{A}_n^2 < \infty \tag{2}$$
and since we're dealing with regular integers, my hope is it converges to something 'nice'.

**Question:**

Is there a way to simplify (1), or much better, analytically derive the convergent value of the infinite sum (2)?

**Some numerical data:**

$\hat{A}_n$ proves as difficult to compute as $A_n$ and convergence is slow. Managed to compute it up to $m=90,000$, which required 21 days of continuous (partially multi-threaded) computing using [ARB](https://arblib.org) at a precision of 165,000 digits, to finally achieve: $2.065078209...$. Some intermediate results are graphed below:

**EDIT:** Have now computed up to $m=110,000$ achieving $2.065459447...$. Also tried to predict higher m-values using 5PL asymmetrical sigmoidal curve fitting. Using this, convergence appears to approach $\frac{31}{15}$, but this could just be some wishful thinking from my side...

[image]

Comment: Two remarks. First, de Reyna actually shows that the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to $\sum A_n^2<\infty$. He also shows that if the Riemann Hypothesis is true, then the sum equals a computable real number lying between $1.266$ and $1.273$. Second, $s\mapsto\log\big((s-1)\,\zeta(s)\big)$ is not a fractional linear transformation, and it does not map the half-plane $\Re(s)>1/2$ onto the unit disk. It is the map $s\mapsto 1-s^{-1}$ that is fractional linear and maps the half-plane $\Re(s)>1/2$ onto the unit disk.

Comment: @GH from MO. Agree with your remarks, I should have phrased both points more precisely in the question. Using an intermediate variable like $z$, as de Reyna does in his paper, to better explain the mapping would have been better. Your remarks definitely improve the question, but I don't think they undermine the core of it, right?